# How to examine the reason behind a performance penalty in HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

I'm accomplishing the same thing, using two different styles.

The **first style** is your ordinary Controller-->Service Layer, where the controller method is defined as:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("opportunities({id:guid})")]
    [Route("opportunities")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetOpportunity()
    {
        var query = Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Last() + Request.RequestUri.Query;
        var response = await _opportunityService.GetOpportunity(query);
        return response;
    }
```

and the service method **GetOpportunity:**

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetOpportunity(string query)
    {
        var response = await Client.Instance.GetAsync(Client.Instance.BaseAddress + query);
        var responseType = response.Result.StatusCode;
        if (responseType == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            return new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = responseType
            };
        return response;
    }
```

The second style is a functional attempt:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FunctionalGetAccount(HttpRequestMessage globalRequest)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequest(globalRequest);
            var query = CreateQuery(request);
            var url = CreateURL(query);
            var proxy = CreateProxy(url);
            var headers = GetHeaders(request);
            AddHeaders(headers, proxy);
            var response = await AwaitResponse(proxy);
            var httpStatusCode = MapHttpStatusCode(response.StatusCode);
            var newHttpResponse = CreateResponse(response, httpStatusCode);
            return newHttpResponse;
        }

        private static HttpStatusCode MapHttpStatusCode(HttpStatusCode input)
        {
            //based on some criteria TBD
            return HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }

        private static HttpResponseMessage CreateResponse(HttpResponseMessage response, HttpStatusCode newStatusCode)
        {
            //should be made immutable
            //update the status code to newStatusCode
            var updatedResponse = response;
            //updatedResponse.StatusCode = newStatusCode;
            //logic TBD
            return updatedResponse;
        }


        private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AwaitResponse(HttpRequest proxy)
        {
            foreach (var header in proxy.Request.Headers)
            {
                Client.Instance.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }

            var response = Client.Instance.SendAsync(proxy.Request);//TREMENDOUSLY SLOW, approximately 15 times slower than first style
            return await response;
        }

        private static void AddHeaders(HttpRequestHeaders headers, HttpRequest proxy)
        {
            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                proxy.Request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
        }

        private static HttpRequestHeaders GetHeaders(HttpRequest request)
        {
            var headers = request.Request.Headers;
            return headers;
        }

        private static HttpRequest CreateProxy(string url)
        {
            var proxy = new HttpRequest(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url)); 
            return proxy;
        }

        private static string CreateURL(string query)
        {
            var url = Client.Instance.BaseAddress + query;
            return url;
        }

        private static string CreateQuery(HttpRequest Request)
        {
            var query = Request.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Last() + Request.Request.RequestUri.Query;
            return query;
        }
```

**This line of code is approximately 15-20 times SLOWER:**

```
var response = Client.Instance.SendAsync(proxy.Request);
```

**Than this line from the first example:**

```
var response = await Client.Instance.GetAsync(Client.Instance.BaseAddress + query);
```

Please note that changing the `SendAsync` to `GetAsync` made no performance impact.

**What am I doing wrong? How do I troubleshoot why the second way is so much slower?**